# How get td click event from bootstrap table?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, events, bootstrap-table

I am trying attribute a event to cells of differents columns of my bootstrap table.

The problem is: Although I have set a class to each column, the events attributed to this classes are not fired. I still tried set a class to each div added in cells, but its event also wasn't fired.

So, how can I get a td event using bootstrab table?

Comment: Please post the code what have you done already?

Comment: CAN YOU POST YOUR CODE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the complete code for td click event for bootstap table

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('table td').click(function(){
     alert($(this).html());
  });
  
  });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  
  <p>Click on the td below</p>            
  <table class="table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Firstname</th>
        <th>Lastname</th>
        <th>Email</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>John</td>
        <td>Doe</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Mary</td>
        <td>Moe</td>
        <td>mary@example.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>July</td>
        <td>Dooley</td>
        <td>july@example.com</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Until you are showing us some code, you can try this,

```
$('body').on('click', '#tableID tr td', function(){
  //whenever any td is clicked, this function will get called
});
```

you can change `'click'` with whatever event name you want to bind your td with.

I am delegating the event to body, because if you dynamically add your table elements to your html, direct binding to those events will not fire/work.

Comment: Suman has the right idea so I'm not going to write a separate answer, but even if you are making dynamic changes, you can bind to an element more deeply nested than 'body'. Bind the listener to the closest ancestor that will not be destroyed. `$('#someContainer')` or whatever. Then in the selector, you don't need to specify the tr, but that's personal choice.

Comment: My plan was to edit/change 'body' to the closest parent element, once Doglas posts some of his code :) upvoting your comment @GregPettit

Answer (score 0):

try This

```
$("#boottable").on('all.bs.table', function (e, name, args) {
            console.log(name, args);
        });
```